# No notification for badges earned on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges, meta

I earned two badges on Meta Stack Overflow today, but while this happened over an hour ago, there's nothing listed in the "Achievements" drop-down.

Is this normal? Is it just caching? Or is something borked?

(They do, of course, appear on the "activity" tab on my user profile page.)

---

A day later and still no entry in "Achievements", so not "caching".

Comment: I just had one pop up ::shrug::

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't get notification for "entry level" bronze badges such as "Supporter" or "Teacher".

You should get notification for "advanced" bronze badges.

You should get notification for all silver and gold badges.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? (Besides here in your answer, I mean.)

Comment: @3524344 I don't think so. But that's what Meta is for - documenting this sort of thing.

Comment: See also: [Which badges do not cause a notification for experienced users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138113/262755)