# No notification of Talkative badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, notifications

I got the "Talkative" badge for my first starred post in chat yesterday. It clearly shows up in my profile.

However, I received no notification for it (and still haven't, nearly a day later). It *could* just be waiting for a script run (I know *some* badges are slow), but normally the badge being awarded and the notification appear at about the same time.

In the mean time, I have received (and been notified of) several badges on the meta site, so notifications in general appear to be working.

Comment: To [quote ChrisF](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252721/3524344): _"You don't get notification for "entry level" bronze badges such as "Supporter" or "Teacher". You should get notification for "advanced" bronze badges. You should get notification for all silver and gold badges."_

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce That meta post explains it exactly. Thanks!